# Update Contacts using Python, Django and Graph

Tags: python, django, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update contacts using Python and Microsoft Graph within a profile page I've created using Django.

I can access contacts and get all the data I need, however I can't work out how to update the fields.

The only information I can find is on the Graph website, however I can't work out how to translate this into usable code:

```
PATCH PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts/
Content-type: application/json

{
  "title": "Mr",
  "givenName": "Steve"
}
```

I assume there is a way to just put this together as a simple link but I cannot work it out. I've tried the following:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts/{id}/title/Mr

PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts/{id}/title:Mr

PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts/{id}/title/$value==Mr
```

but they all produce errors

There are no tutorials for doing this with Python on the Microsoft site and it's proving very difficult to find any info on it. So hopefully someone can help out.

Cheers!

!!!!!!!!!!!!! UPDATE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Here is my current code which still sadly does nothing:

In my views.py:

```
def profile(request):
  if request.session['has_id']==False:
    contact_id = request.session['contact_id'] = request.POST.get('edit')
    request.session['has_id'] = True
  else:
    contact_id = request.session['contact_id']
  context = ct.profile(request,id=request.session.get('contact_id'),init=initialize_context,get_tok=get_token)
  if request.method=="PATCH":
    ct.update(contact_id,'title',request.PATCH.get('title'))
  return render(request, 'tutorial/profile.html', context)
```

and my updater:

```
def update(id,key,value):
  url = '{}/me/contacts/{}'.format(graph_url,id)
  payload = {key : value}

  head = {
    "Content-type" : "application/json",
  }

  requests.patch(url=url,data=payload,headers=head)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out, I thought I'd tried something like this yesterday but apparently not.

Here's how to do it!

views.py

```
def profile(request):
  if request.session['has_id']==False:
    contact_id = request.session['contact_id'] = request.POST.get('edit')
    request.session['has_id'] = True
  else:
    contact_id = request.session['contact_id']
  context = ct.profile(request,id=request.session.get('contact_id'),init=initialize_context,get_tok=get_token)
  if request.method=="PATCH":
    ct.update(contact_id,'title',request.PATCH.get('title'))
  return render(request, 'tutorial/profile.html', context)
```

contacts_helper.py:

```
def update(token,id,key,value):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
  url = '{}/me/contacts/{}'.format(graph_url,id)
  payload = {key : value}

  graph_client.patch(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Obviously if you're looking at this you've probably already set up auth_helper.py and graph_helper.py but if you haven't then you should head over the Microsoft Graph website and follow these instructions:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/python